# Populating Bootstrap Card Groups with the desired number of cards using Angular directives

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using Angular 9.1.8.

I am building an Angular component using using Bootstrap Card Groups and Cards.  I am using my cards groups to ensure that when displaying a larger result set of cards that more than two cards display in a given row.  Consider the following 4 cards:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-group">
     <!-- card 1 -->
    <div class="card bg-light text-dark">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/trucking_placeholder2.png" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
           <h6 class="card-title"> <i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> ABC Truck Repair</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="float-right">$75/hr | 2.6 miles</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">123 Main Street Idaho Falls, ID 83401</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"> 208-970-9341</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
     <!-- card 2 -->
    <div class="card bg-light text-dark">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/trucking_placeholder2.png" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h6 class="card-title"> <i class="fas fa-circle text-warning"></i> ABC Truck Repair</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="float-right">$75/hr | 2.6 miles</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">123 Main Street Idaho Falls, ID 83401</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"> 208-970-9341</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-group">
    <!-- card 3 -->
    <div class="card bg-light text-dark">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/trucking_placeholder2.png" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h6 class="card-title"> <i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> ABC Truck Repair</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="float-right">$75/hr | 2.6 miles</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">123 Main Street Idaho Falls, ID 83401</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"> 208-970-9341</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card 4 -->
    <div class="card bg-light text-dark">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/trucking_placeholder2.png" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h6 class="card-title"> <i class="fas fa-circle text-danger"></i> ABC Truck Repair</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="float-right">$75/hr | 2.6 miles</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">123 Main Street Idaho Falls, ID 83401</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"> 208-970-9341</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With my limited understanding of the `*ngFor` directive I can do the following:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-group">
     <!-- card 1 -->
    <div *ngFor="let s of shops;" class="card bg-light text-dark">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/trucking_placeholder2.png" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
           <h6 class="card-title"> <i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> {{s.name}}</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="float-right">${{s.laborRate}}/hr | 2.6 miles</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">{{s.address}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"> {{s.phone}}</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't help me keep only two cards to a give group.

If I want to end up with only two cards to a group how would I do this using Angular directives?  Is there some other way I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

After you get your data, you could organize it into a two-dimensional array where you have an array of 2 cards in each array element. Then in your HTML, you could use two `*ngFor` directives where the outer loop will create your card-groups and the inner loop will populate the 2 cards.

Comment: I think I have an idea of how this would go.  Could you provide an example?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle I figured out I wasn't going to be able to use pure bootstrap to solve my problem.  I solved my problem by actually taking my `*ngFor` angular directive out of card groups.  Using super basic CSS-Grids I was able to achieve a two column layout very easily using the following below:

First I added the class `.grid-container` to the parent container holding my cards.

```html
<div class="container grid-container">
  <div *ngFor="let s of shops;" class="card bg-light text-dark">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/trucking_placeholder2.png" alt="Card image">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h6 class="card-title"> <i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> {{s.name}}</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="float-right">${{s.laborRate}}/hr | 2.6 miles</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">{{s.address}}</p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"> {{s.phone}}</i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I added the following CSS:

The `display: grid` says that I want to use CSS Grids.
The `grid-template-columns: auto auto;` says two create a column layout whose dimension are determined by the child. (bootstrap takes care of each card styling in my example)

Then just for a responsiveness I added the media query that basically says when my screen size gets smaller than 600px, then display as inherited from bootstrap which is a single stretch out 1 column layout which works well in mobile.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: inherit;
    grid-template-columns: inherit;
  }
}
```

Simple as that.  Card Groups as good as they were for styling simply added to much complexity when trying to dynamically generates the cards on the fly.